# How to model pagination when data is spanning over multiple blocks

Tags: java, algorithm, database-design

I have generic problem where I am loading data from backend in blocks i.e. in pages.I have created cache which stores maximum 2-3 pages at a time.
Say page 1 - 1-1000
Page 1001-2000

```
class page{
List<Data>, startoffset, endoffset, pageno}
```

Here client could be UI or any other service.

Now client is asking for data from 1-100,101-200. Till the time the range is being served from one page, I can accommodate the changes by calculating page no from supplied range.

If page no is not there, I can load that range from backend and keep it in cache.

However, I am facing issue when client request for data that overlaps over multiple blocks.
example- when client asks for Page 950-1050, then data is spanning over two pages.

Any suggestion on how to model classes/blocks in such case i.e. how to keep server side data in memory in blocks and send it to GUI.

Comment: You can't really expect to cache a part of the data, then be able to handle requests that may overlap cached data and non-cached data. If the UI asks data in 100 item pages, is it too slow to get the data directly from the datasource? The caching is probably causing you more problems than it's helping you at this time.

Comment: @Kayaman I need to do caching, however in my application, I can control which part of data to cache. My query is -> How to design on server side that can handle overlapping requests for data.

Comment: This is actually the basic idea of caching: when you have a cache miss you fetch it, there's no way around it. You might want to minimize cache misses of course, but you can't possibly predict all scenarios. If a user asks for `950-1050` and another one for `949-1051`, you'll still have cache misses.

Comment: @RGoyal it can be advantageous to do caching afterwards. If you design cache-first, you might end up with inefficient design which depends on knowing that the implementation uses cache. If you design it first so it doesn't use caches, tune queries and make sure you're not doing anything silly, you then have caching left in your toolbox to get even better performance. It's like installing an afterburner into a car with a tiny motor, you'd be better off tuning the car first, *then* installing the afterburner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in using two (or even more) contiguous blocks fetched from DB enough to cover the region requested for ui. You can do it both eagerly and lazyly ( that is discover that you don't have enough rows and fetch extra). This is pretty normal situation for the kind of process you try to execute. Overlapping is present always in cases when user is free to choose desired region

Comment: One problem with that is that the user might request pages between `1` and `1000000`, and you end up using 1000 cache blocks. And if there's more data you can't possibly predict / cache all of it.

Comment: @Anton Astafiev, How I can model this kind of secanrio on server side where user is free to choose desire region?

Comment: @ChatterOne , this will never be case in my applicationsi.e. cachine 100_000 pages

Comment: let's assume some numbers. UI requests Nu = Nend - Nstart rows. If you load data only in blocks of predefined size M (which is not very good actually), then you need to load blocks from [Nstart / M]-th to [Nend / M]-th. These numbers are for eager load. You put these block into cache and select appropriate region for ui.

Comment: @AntonAstafiev If Fixing block size is not good idea, what other strategy youwill suggest>

Comment: Look above, I suggested loading necessary blocks, it's most obvious way. But in fact your situation is not clear enough. Why can't you change block size, why can't load several blocks, why you use caching. Is it required at least?